# Does the ActivityResult contain any info of the activity (such as class name) has just called setResult when using registerForActivityResult callback?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-launcher, startactivityforresult

I am at activity A, and launching some other activities such as B and C with the launcher like this

```
private val resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
        if (it.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // any way to get activity name that set the result?
        }
    }

// Launch activity B by a button click
resultLauncher.launch(Intent(this, B::class.java))

// Launch activity C by a button click
resultLauncher.launch(Intent(this, C::class.java))
```

When finishing both B and C, I use this code

```
setResult(RESULT_OK) // don't want to put Intent data to this method
finish()
```

So Does the ActivityResult param in registerForActivityResult contain any info of the activities (such as simpleClassName) that call setResult and go back to activity A? I don't want to put the intent data to setResult method

Comment: Why not just create a `bResultLauncher` and a `cResultLauncher`?

Comment: Well i think you can easily achieve it by providing activity name from activity where you are setting result . Don't you want to use that way ?

Comment: I was aware what you mentioned but I want to know that if the ActivityResult contains any info of the activities that call setResult (such as class name, ect.). Sorry for my bad description. I have just made it clear. Please take a look at again @ianhanniballake

Comment: Yup! that way could be done my expectation but not the way I want. And I have just made my question more sense. Please take a look at again. Thank you @jayeshgurudayalani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So Does the ActivityResult param in registerForActivityResult contain any info of the activities (such as simpleClassName) that call setResult and go back to activity A?

No. [The documentation for `ActivityResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/result/ActivityResult) shows that it contains the result code `Int` and the `Intent` that get delivered to `onActivityResult()`.